# Bundling and minification issue in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I have bundled my js files, which run fine on dev environment. However on QA we have couple of issues.

1. .min.js.map  of few files like "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js", "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" cause issue. If I delete .map files application works smoothly, else shows error some thing like, error in minification, too many error not a valid js file..
2. Both dev and QA are on https, on dev scripts are successfully loaded, but in QA it always show alert for unsafe script in chrome, stating that application was loaded on https but trying to load script from http.

Answer (score 0):

1. The *.map files are used by visual studio internally exclusively for intellisense purposes. If it is showing any weird messages it is because of this but this should not effect your application's performance in any way.
2. The @Scripts.Render helper will use the same URL scheme as the page request, so it will use HTTPS if the request was originally made that way. I would recommend using the Net tab of a browser's development tools to see if any other related files are coming in over HTTP and not HTTPS. This is usually caused by a web font or a IMG or something.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I think 1. -vsdoc is used for intellisense, not .map. It is effecting functionality, that is why it is weird. 2. I checked network tab, there is not other script loading, in dev it hits for https and qa it hits for http